# Why is "start in" needed for Windows scheduled tasks?

Tags: windows, scheduled-task

We develop a web application that can be deployed on Windows or Linux. The Linux implementation uses cron, and the Windows one uses scheduled tasks to run a single PHP script that processes all scheduled tasks for our system.

The task is scheduled using `schtasks` during the install process, like:

This has always worked both under W2003 and W2008. A week ago a customer reported that scheduled tasks were not running. He is running on Windows 2008. We checked over and over and finally solved the issue by entering the folder that contains the .vbs script as the "start in" folder for the scheduled task.

This said, there is no way to set up the "start in..." value from `schtasks` without using an XML definition of the tasks. XML definitions don't work in Windows 2003, so I would have to add windows version detection to the installer, additional testing, etc (I'd like to avoid this if at all possible).

The only atypical thing I noticed about the install is that the system is installed in `D:\` as opposed to the default `C:\Program Files (x86)\`, but I don't see how this would matter. All the paths are absolute in all the scripts.

Can anyone suggest a reasonable solution for this?

Comment: I finally traced this to a buggy PHP encoding module (SourceGuardian). Although there were no relative paths whatsoever on the scripts, encoded scripts failed to run without "start in" set if they were installed below drive letter other than C:. I ended up wrapping the call in a batch script that did "cd <DRIVE>" before the call and everything worked.

Answer (score 8):

The "start in" is mainly to make sure that if you have relative paths in the task to run it understands which directory to run the script in.

That said, this link might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1020023/specifying-start-in-directory-in-schtasks-command-in-windows

Comment: In theory yes, but in practice not really. My script has absolute paths all over and can be run from cmd starting in C:\ or anywhere else without problems. It's just the scheduler that chokes on it.

Comment: Is the scheduler choking on it if you run it manually as that same logged in user that you can run it anywhere?  You should delve into why it "has always worked" and suddenly doesn't.

Comment: The task is run as system, so I can't really reproduce the environment myself, can I? It's not that it has "always worked", I'm thinking it may have never worked but this only happens on specific setups. It works fine on our testing environments, but I have seen a number of customer servers where it doesn't without the "start in" setting. Maybe it has to do with UAC or a security policy?

Comment: And maybe you missed one of those hard-coded paths somewhere?

Comment: @GomoX - you said in your first comment here: "can be run from cmd starting in C:\ or anywhere else without problems".  But then say you can't reproduce it.  Which is it?  It doesn't really matter if you can run it from cmd on your dev environment...testing with the customer is what will be required in a real world environment.  Or you can call it a day and just say "add the start in" in your install docs.

Answer (score 2):

Solution to what, exactly?

The `start in` value is exactly what it sounds like, the directory in which the application/program/script starts.  This matters for when it calls other resources.  If it calls `somecustom.exe` that's not in that `start in` directory, it won't be found, and your application/program/script will error out.  If you call absolutely everything by path, it shouldn't matter, but the behavior you're describing would seem to indicate it's not actually doing that, so you could try to correct that behavior, or a quick workaround (if ugly and kind of crappy solution to actually getting the code right) would be adding the directory to the `%PATH%` variable, so Windows will always check the directory when an executable file is called without a referenced path.

If you're working in Windows 2008/7/Vista, you can also [use a switch set the `start in` directory with `schtasks /v1`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/447774/specifying-the-running-directory-for-scheduled-tasks-using-schtasks-exe), so long as you're not trying to run the tasks under the `SYSTEM` account.  I think I'd prefer to make the developer debug his code, but YMMV.

Comment: I'm the developer, and everything is set with an absolute path. The same command works fine under Windows 2003. So there shouldn't be any need for the "start in" setting. Still, no dice on some installs.